# Produce two versions of output from R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using R Markdown to create practice sheets for students. For this purpose, I would like to render both a) the practice sheet itself and b) the practice sheet with solutions displayed directly.

I am currently using a solution that allows me to switch between producing the practice sheet and the solution sheet by doing the following:

The yaml-header includes:

```
header-includes:
 - \usepackage{comment}
params:
  soln: TRUE
```

Then I write the solutions like this:

```
`r if(!params$soln) {"\\begin{comment}"}`

Here goes text or code.

`r if(!params$soln) {"\\end{comment}"}`
```

By changing the `soln` parameter, I can control which output I get. This works fine, but I could imagine an even more efficient way.

Does anybody know a way to have R Markdown produce two output file simultaneously, one with `soln: TRUE` and one with `soln: FALSE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `rmarkdown::render` two times with appropriate arguments:

```
rmarkdown::render("practice-sheets.Rmd", output_file = "practice.pdf", params = list(soln = TRUE))
rmarkdown::render("practice-sheets.Rmd", output_file = "solution.pdf", params = list(soln = FALSE))
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much :-)